# Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

"Еще чуть-чуть и мы окажемся на границе штата".
Скажите, в этом предложении нужна запятая перед "и"?

Answer (score 1):

Да, это сложное предложение. Возможно также тире - вторая часть содержит неожиданный результат. (нужен контекст для верного ответа)

Answer (score -1):

Насчет запятой не уверен, а вот тире, считаю, поставить имеет смысл:

"Еще чуть-чуть - и мы окажемся на границе штата".

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/7431)

Comment: "Кому и кобыла невеста..." (Это я опять же не про вас-с, про ответ.)